# tomcat7 + apache2 port 8081 conflict?

Tags: apache2, tomcat7

Picking up a test system with apache + tomcat. It was supposed to work but has been not working for a while.

If I start Tomcat first, then when starting apache it will show the following error:

[warn] NameVirtualHost *:8081 has no VirtualHosts
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8081
no listening sockets available, shutting down

If I start Apache first, then start Tomcat, I will see the java exception saying port 8081 has been used already and Tomcat won't start.

What's the correct way to integrate apache2 and tomcat7? Where do I may be missing in the current setup? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since port 8081 is not the standard port for Apache to listen to, it must be configured somewhere explicitly. Go through the configuration, find it, and fix it.

Alternatively, you can go though the tomcat configuration, find the port and fix it.

What the fix may be depends on your server setup: Moving it to another port number, disabling it completly, or something different.

A common configuration hides apache tomcat completly behind apache httpd and connects to it via the AJP connector.

Answer (score 0):

You have the apache configure these listening on port 80 and integrate the Tomcat (default ajp port 8009 or default http port 8080) via mod_jk (AJP) or proxypass (AJP or HTTP) to Apache.

Apache (proxypass)

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

or

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

Comment: The Tomcat port for AJP and HTTP connector is configured in server.xml. The Apache depending on configuration and Linux distribution in different files (httpd.conf apache.conf etc.)